# Posting source code to blog - Control with scrollbar & keep formatting

Tags: controls, blogs

We are looking for a control we can use in our WordPress blogs that will keep our source code formatting and provide scrollbars. I know I have seen this control in use but cannot find a name or source for them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Prettify, but not in WordPress - there's a WordPress plugin for it here though:

http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/google-code-prettify-for-wordpress/